# Tweaking Photoshop transform JavaScript to include scaling variable

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

So after looking around I finally found a something works almost as I need. I plan to use applescript to pass it variables. That said we get to the javascript. I don't know it well and still trying to pick it up.

Can anyone help me add in some code to included scaling the image after the anchor point is defined. The current code also needs the user to confirm the setting. Since I am passing variables I don't need it to do that. I think all i need to do is change "DialogModes.ALL" to "DialogModes.NO"

```
function transform( x, y) {// anchor position as pixels  
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();  
        var ref = new ActionReference();  
        ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );  
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref );  
    desc.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('FTcs'), charIDToTypeID('QCSt'), charIDToTypeID('Qcsi') );  
        var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();  
        desc7.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Hrzn'), charIDToTypeID('#Rlt'), x );  
        desc7.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Vrtc'), charIDToTypeID('#Rlt'), y );  
    desc.putObject( charIDToTypeID('Pstn'), charIDToTypeID('Pnt '), desc7 );  
    desc.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Wdth'), charIDToTypeID('#Prc'), 100 );  
    desc.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Hght'), charIDToTypeID('#Prc'), 100 );  
    desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID('Lnkd'), true );  
    desc.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Intr'), charIDToTypeID('Intp'), charIDToTypeID('Bcbc') );  
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Trnf'), desc, DialogModes.ALL );  
};  

transform( 584, 330)
```

I am looking for the function input to look like this in the end.

```
transform( 584, 330, 50, 50)
```

That would make 584=X, 330=y Pixel anchor and the 50, 50 would be the percents of the x,y scale.

Any help to polish this would be greatly appreciated. I need to use this as part of a batch action for 10,000 images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function definition to

```
function transform(x, y, w, h) {
```

and change the lines starting with `desc.putUnitDouble` to the following:

```
desc.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Wdth'), charIDToTypeID('#Prc'), w );  
desc.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Hght'), charIDToTypeID('#Prc'), h );
```